# Dplyr head function prints # a tibble

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

i am having a problem with dplyr's head() function. I am using it to print the top 3 elemts of a dataframe I grouped and sorted before.

```
  output$text_pzs <- renderPrint({
       print(head(top3_pzs(), 3))
  })
```

I am using Shiny so that i have to use it that way.

The output is correct but it shows additional information like this:

[Output on the dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZUxx.png)

Is it possible to get rid of the info?

## A tibble: 3 x 2

Projektname             n

I think this is a basic problem so that i don't need to upload more data, do I?

Answer (score 1):

Some upfront clarifications: `head` is not part of dplyr but included in R's basic set of packages. It's also not the `head` function that's causing you trouble but the fact that there is a special tibble print-method for printing ..tibbles (your dataframe is coerced to tibble once you start grouping / arranging with dplyr functions). You can go back to standard printing behavior by using the (normal) `print.data.frame` print method explicitly or by converting the tibble to `data.frame` before printing.

Your code could be something like:

```
output$text_pzs <- renderPrint({
   print.data.frame(head(top3_pzs(), 3))
})
```

or

```
output$text_pzs <- renderPrint({
   print(as.data.frame(head(top3_pzs(), 3)))
})
```

Comment: Well that did the trick. Thanks a lot. I am not used to dplyr at the moment. Seems like there is a lot to learn.